# Invert png image

Tags: code-golf, graphical-output, image-processing

Create program or function that takes file name as an argument or reads it from standard input, and completes the following task:

1. Read image from a png file (name given as argument).
2. Reverse colors in that image, so that for example dark green (0, 75, 30) would become (255, 180, 225) (because 255-0=255, 255-75=180 and 255-30=225). You should not change alpha channel value.
3. Output that image to a file called `a.png` (in png format), or show it in GUI window.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). Standard loopholes apply.

Comment: Is it required to support any optional png features? Are built-in png loading/writing functions acceptable?

Comment: @Sparr Optional feature support is *optional*. Built-in functions are not explicitly disallowed, so I'll assume they are allowed.

Comment: PNG files can be indexed (each pixel contains a pointer to a color in the colormap) or truecolor (each pixel contains the actual color). Which one do we need to support? Can we choose? In fact, there are [five](https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/#6Colour-values) different subformats regarding color. So... ?

Comment: @DonMuesli I think any method that provides correct result will be fine. You can assume that the color isn't greyscale, and supporting alpha-channel is optional. I think that using any other mode is acceptable, as long as the task will still be reversing the colors, and colors have (r,g,b)-values.

Comment: Can I use just CSS?

Answer (score 29):

## ImageMagick `display -fx`, 3 <strike>7</strike> <strike>18</strike> <strike>24</strike> bytes

```
1-u
```

The ImageMagick tool `display` with the `fx` parameter can apply the above program to a png given as the parameter and display the results on screen.

Check out [my post on meta](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/8828/is-imagemagick-a-programming-language) about ImageMagick as a programming language. I wrote a prime tester over there as a proof of concept.

Re byte counting, `display -fx code filename` is equivalent to `perl -e code filename`, where we traditionally count just `code` for length.

Comment: Is this not a standard loophole? It's gotten plenty of upvotes, but it seems like it should be. I guess if Mathematica can have a bunch of these functions built-in, then using any pre-released application (before the asking of the question) to do it for you is fair game, so long as it accepts command-line arguments?

Comment: @NateDiamond Give me about 5 minutes to finish my meta post about "is imagemagick a programming language" and I'll cut this down to 7 bytes and address your question at the same time :)

Comment: @NateDiamond http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/8828/is-imagemagick-a-programming-language

Answer (score 21):

### Pyth, <s>16</s> <s>15</s> 13 bytes

```
.w-LLL255'z\a
```

Outputs to `a.png`.

```
          z    read input
         '     read as RGB triples from file
   LLL         map over rows, then triples, then individual values...
  -   255      ...subtract from 255
.w         \a  write as image to a.png
```

Thanks to [Jakube](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/29577/jakube) for 2 bytes!

Comment: man, i've gotta learn pyth

Comment: Does Pyth not have bitwise negation (`~` or similar)?

Comment: @PeterTaylor I don't think it does, surprisingly. (In any case, it would have to be restricted to 8 bits.)

Comment: is there no way to deeply-map with a pfn?

Comment: @ven Nope, I don't think so (or at least not the ways I've tried). You can't nest `L`s or `R`s.

Comment: too bad, that'd be very fun :D. I remember having tried such things.

Comment: @ven @Doorknob Actually you can do it: `.w-LLL255'z\a`. But don't ask me how this works or why you need `LLL` and not something like `LMM`.

Comment: paging @isaacg, maybe?

Comment: @ven [Pinging](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/236085) only works for users that have authored, commented  or edited the post

Comment: haha, okay, noted :P. (note: [to page](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/page) exists)

Comment: @Jakube from looking at the code, it seems to require that because `L` parses in a kind of odd way with other sugar parsing. The `L` parse seems to keep the other `L`s as part of the body of the map, so after the first parse you get: `.wm-LL255d'z\a` and so on. I'm not sure what's up with `M` though, I'll ping isaac in the Pyth chatroom.

Comment: @Jakube O_o I have no idea why that works, but thanks!

Answer (score 18):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 10 bytes

```
255iYi-IYG
```

There are [five different subformats](https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/#6Colour-values) of PNG, depending on how color is encoded. None of them seems to be more "optional" than the others. I chose the most flexible one, `Truecolor`, in which each pixel can have an arbitrary color. The above code also supports `Truecolor with alpha`, ignoring the alpha channel.

To know the color subformat of a PNG file: look for the byte sequence `[73 72 68 82]` near the beginning of the file; and the [*tenth*](https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/#11IHDR) byte from there will have one of the five values in the [table linked above](https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/#6Colour-values).

#### How the code works

Pretty straightforward:

```
255    % push 255 to the stack
i      % input filename with extension '.png'
Yi     % read contents of that file as (truecolor) image
-      % subtract
IYG    % show image
```

#### Example

I couldn't resist seeing myself inverted, so I downloaded [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFMSx.png?s=328&g=1) (which is in subformat `Truecolor with alpha`), ran the code (second line is user input)

```
>> matl 255iYi-IYG
> 'C:\Users\Luis\Desktop\me.png'
```

and got

[image]

Comment: Your avatar is actually you? I thought it was just your helmet! :P

Comment: I thought PNG and all means long code, but 10 bytes? Wow.

Answer (score 17):

## Java, 295

```java
import javax.imageio.*;class V{public static void main(String[]a)throws
Exception{java.awt.image.BufferedImage m=ImageIO.read(new
java.io.File(a[0]));for(int
x=m.getWidth(),y;x-->0;)for(y=m.getHeight();y-->0;)m.setRGB(x,y,m.getRGB(x,y)^-1>>>8);ImageIO.write(m,"png",new
java.io.File("a.png"));}}
```

Comment: I like how x-- and x>0 together make a litte arrow showing that x goes up to 0. Why have I never seen/used that before?

Comment: Import `java.io.File`?

Comment: @LuWi hehe, I've seen and used it before, [some people](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-name-of-the-operator) call it the "goes to" operator, and it's pretty golfy :)

Comment: @nickb even if you use the shorter `import java.io.*;`, it doesn't save any bytes but actually increases the size.

Answer (score 4):

## R, 124 bytes

```
p=png::readPNG(readline());p[,,-4]=1-p[,,-4];png("a.png",h=nrow(p),w=ncol(p));par(mar=rep(0,4));plot(as.raster(p));dev.off()
```

Reads in file name through stdin (`readline()`).

```R
p=png::readPNG(readline()) #Reads in png as an RGBA array on range [0,1]
p[,,-4]=1-p[,,-4] #Takes the opposite value except on alpha layer
png("a.png",h=nrow(p),w=ncol(p)) #Prepares output png of same size as input
par(mar=rep(0,4)) #Makes the png take the full space of the figure region
plot(as.raster(p)) #Transforms p as a raster so that it can be plotted as is.
dev.off() #Closes the plotting device.
```

Example Input/Output using the first png I found on this computer :)

[image: Input] [image: Output]

Answer (score 3):

## CSS, 19 Bytes

```
*{filter:invert(1)}
```

http://output.jsbin.com/suqayudoyu

Comment: The two images don't appear to have any change.

Comment: Use Firefox, http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters

Answer (score 2):

## Tcl, 176 bytes

```
foreach r [[image c photo -file {*}$argv] d] {set x {}
foreach c $r {lappend x [format #%06X [expr "0xFFFFFF-0x[string ra $c 1 end]"]]}
lappend y $x}
image1 p $y
image1 w a.png
```

Loads the PNG via the `photo` image type, gets the image data, converting each row and color by subtracting from #FFFFFF, then writes the file back to disk (as "a.png").

For best results, use TrueColor PNGs, since Tk will try to use the same color resolution as the source image data.

To see the image without sampling problems, add

```
pack [label .i -image image1]
```

to the end. (Obviously, this is longer than the disk-save option.)

Comment: You can ave bytes replacing `foreach`by `lmap`

Answer (score 2):

### Mathematica, 140 bytes

```
Export["a.png",SetAlphaChannel[ColorCombine[Most@#],Last@#]&@MapAt[Image[1-ImageData@#]&,ColorSeparate[Import[#],{"R","G","B","A"}],{;;3}]]&
```

Comment: Note that you can save two bytes by changing `Import[#]` to `Import@#`, and same for `ColorCombine[Most@#]`.

Comment: Why wouldn't a simple `ColorNegate@*Import` be a complete answer?

Answer (score 2):

## cmd + IrfanView, 19 characters

```batch
i_view32 %1 /invert
```

Just the expensive alternative of [Sparr](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/4787/sparr)'s [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/76418).

Answer (score 2):

## Julia, <s>94</s> 79 bytes

```
using FileIO
save(ARGS[1],map(x->typeof(x)(1-x.r,1-x.g,1-x.b,1),load(ARGS[1])))
```

This is a full program that takes a file name as a command line argument and overwrites the given file with the inverted image. It requires that the `FileIO` and `Image` package be installed. The latter doesn't need to be imported though.

Call the program from the command line like `julia filename.jl /path/to/image.png`.

Ungolfed:

```
using FileIO # required for reading and writing image files

# Load the given image into a matrix where each element is an RGBA value
a = load(ARGS[1])

# Construct a new image matrix as the inverse of `a` by, for each element
# `x` in `a`, constructing a new RGBA value as 1 - the RGB portions of
# `x`, but with an alpha of 1 to avoid transparency.
b = map(x -> typeof(x)(1 - x.r, 1 - x.g, 1 - x.b, 1), a)

# Save the image using the same filename
save(ARGS[1], b)
```

Example:

[image: regular] [image: inverted]

Comment: The magpie (?) looks seriously depressed on the second image.

Answer (score 1):

### Python + PIL, 85 bytes

```py
from PIL import Image
lambda a:Image.eval(Image.open(a),lambda x:255-x).save('a.png')
```

This defines an anonymous function that takes a filename as a string and saves the resultant image to `a.png`.

Test run:

[image: llama]
[image: llama out]

Comment: -3 bytes: `from PIL import Image as I`, followed by replacing `Image` in the function with `I`

Comment: I'm fairly sure that simply `import Image` will work, shaving off a whole load of bytes

Comment: save 11 bytes with `from PIL.Image import*`

Comment: I think this accidentally inverts the alpha channel as well. Apparently the `eval` function runs against all "bands", including the alpha one. Here is what I get when inverting the Firefox logo - https://imgur.com/a/wV3MSQX

Comment: @dana Per [the OP's comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/76417/invert-png-image/79223?noredirect=1#comment186199_76417), supporting alpha channels is optional.

Comment: OK - Cool deal :) I might update my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

## C + stb_image + stb_image_write, <del>175</del> 162 bytes (or +72=<del>247</del> 234)

My first submission on this site ever.

```
#include"stb_image.h"
#include"stb_image_write.h"
x,y,c,i;f(char*d){d=stbi_load(d,&x,&y,&c,i=0);for(;i<x*y*c;i++)d[i]=255-d[i];stbi_write_png("a.png",x,y,c,d,0);}
```

---

Could probably shave off a few bytes. Needs `stb_*` implementation to either be in a separate library, or at the start of this file with:

```
#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#define STB_IMAGE_WRITE_IMPLEMENTATION
```

I didn't include it in the count because it's essentially part of the library (esp. if it's compiled separately). +72 bytes to add that if required, however.

---

#### Update 1:

Realized only a function (as opposed to an entire program) is acceptable, shaving off 15 bytes. The ***old*** implementation (which is an entire program), for reference:

```
x,y,i;main(int c,char**d){*d=stbi_load(d[1],&x,&y,&c,0);for(;i<x*y*c;i++)i[*d]=255-i[*d];stbi_write_png("a.png",x,y,c,*d,0);}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java, <s>300</s> 298 bytes

```
import javax.swing.*;void c(String f)throws Exception{java.awt.image.BufferedImage r=javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(new java.io.File(f));for(int i=0;i++<r.getWidth();)for(int j=0;j++<r.getHeight();)r.setRGB(i,j,(0xFFFFFF-r.getRGB(i,j))|0xFF000000);JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,new ImageIcon(r));}
```

Answer (score 1):

## MATLAB / Octave, 31 bytes

**Code:**

```
imshow(imcomplement(imread(x)))
```

**Example:**

```
imshow(imcomplement(imread('balloons.png')))
```

[image]              [image]

**Explanation:**

Read the image, `x`, from a graphics file, complement the image, and then display the image.

Comment: The code assumes that `x` is predefined, which is not allowed. You can turn it into a lambda function for +4 bytes with `@(x)`.

Answer (score 0):

### FFmpeg, 10 bytes

Edit: Taking a cue from @Sparr's answer

```
-vf negate
```

(the above when passed to ffplay alongwith the image name, will display the negated image)

---

```
ffplay %1 -vf negate
```

The above is saved as a batch file.

Comment: Is FFmpeg a programming language by our standards? I don't know enough about it to be sure. Perhaps ask on meta?

Answer (score 0):

## Racket 282 bytes

```
(λ(fname)(let*((i(make-object bitmap% fname))(w(send i get-width))(h(send i get-height))(pixels(make-bytes(* w h 4)))(i2(make-object bitmap% w h)))
(send i get-argb-pixels 0 0 w h pixels)(send i2 set-argb-pixels 0 0 w h(list->bytes(map(lambda(x)(- 255 x))(bytes->list pixels))))i2))
```

More readable form:

```
(define(f fname)
  (let*(
        (i (make-object bitmap% fname))
        (w (send i get-width))
        (h (send i get-height))
        (pixels (make-bytes(* w h 4)))
        (i2 (make-object bitmap% w h)))
    (send i get-argb-pixels 0 0 w h pixels)
    (send i2 set-argb-pixels 0 0 w h
          (list->bytes
           (map
            (lambda(x) (- 255 x))
            (bytes->list pixels))))
    i2))
```

Usage:

```
(f "myimg.png")
```

Answer (score 0):

### Golang, 311 bytes

```
package main
import("image"
."image/png"
."image/color"
."os")
func main(){f,_:=Open(Args[1])
i,_:=Decode(f)
q:=i.Bounds()
n:=image.NewRGBA(q)
s:=q.Size()
for x:=0;x<s.X;x++{for y:=0;y<s.Y;y++{r,g,b,a:=i.At(x,y).RGBA()
n.Set(x,y,RGBA{byte(255-r),byte(255-g),byte(255-b),byte(a)})}}
o,_:=Create("o")
Encode(o,n)}
```

#### ungolfed

```
package main
import(
    "image"
    "image/png"
    "image/color"
    "os"
)

func main(){
    // open a png image.
    f, _ := os.Open(Args[1])

    // decode the png image to a positive image object(PIO).
    p, _ := png.Decode(f)

    // get a rectangle from the PIO.
    q := p.Bounds()

    // create a negative image object(NIO).
    n := image.NewRGBA(q)

    // get the size of the PIO.
    s := q.Size()

    // invert the PIO.
    for x := 0; x < s.X; x++ {
        for y := 0; y < s.Y; y++ {
            // fetch the value of a pixel from the POI.
            r, g, b, a := p.At(x, y).RGBA()

            // set the value of an inverted pixel to the NIO.
            // Note: byte is an alias for uint8 in Golang.
            n.Set(x, y, color.RGBA{uint8(255-r), uint8(255-g), uint8(255-b), uint8(a)})
        }
    }

    // create an output file.
    o, _ := os.Create("out.png")


    // output a png image from the NIO.
    png.Encode(o, n)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/) + [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/), 55 bytes

```python
import cv2
cv2.imwrite('a.png',255-cv2.imread(input()))
```

The OpenCV library uses NumPy arrays to read, process, and write images. Below is an example of this script inverting an image found on [mozilla.org](https://mozilla.org/).

[image: Edge Artwork Inverted]

All channels, including the alpha channel, will be inverted. This is problematic for images that have transparency. But as @Mego pointed out, support for the alpha channel is optional.

Below is an 82 byte commented version that property handles the alpha channel.

```python
import cv2                # import OpenCV library
i=cv2.imread(input(),-1)  # image file name is specified from stdin
                          # read with the IMREAD_UNCHANGED option
                          # to preserve transparency
i[:,:,:3]=255-i[:,:,:3]   # invert R,G,B channels
cv2.imwrite('a.png',i)    # output to a file named a.png
```

As shown below, this properly handles inverting the Firefox logo while preserving the transparent background.

[image: Firefox Logo Inverted]